# return the argument of a trigonometric function

Tags: functions

Does any one knows a function or a way to return the argument of a trigonometric function in Mathematica? I have the following code and wanted to operate (differentiate) on the argument of the cosinus function that results.

```
chplus = ComplexExpand[Re[ExpToTrig[E^(I*(phi0 + 2*π*((k*t^2)/2 + f0*t)))]]]
```

This results in

> ```
> Cos[phi0 + 2 f0 π t + k π t^2]
> ```

In sagemath I can acomplish this by doing:

```
var('t, phi0, f0, f1, T', domain=RR);
k = (f1 - f0)/T;
chplus = real(e^(i*(f0 + k*t^2/2 + f0*t)));
chplus.operands()[0]
```

and the response returned is exactly what I want

> ```
> f0*t - 1/2*f0*t^2/T + 1/2*f1*t^2/T + f0
> ```

Comment: Everything in *Mathematica* is an expression: `First@Cos[phi0 + 2 f0 \[Pi] t + k \[Pi] t^2]`. Is this what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand, but `chplus[[1]]`?

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, all expressions in Mathematica can be accessed as they were part of a nested list. Therefore, it doesn't matter if you have `Cos[x]` or `List[x]` (which is nothing more than `{x}`). You simply can extract the first element by

```
Cos[phi0 + 2 f0 π t + k π t^2][[1]]
```

Inside your `Cos` you have a sum. If you like to have the second part of the sum, you can just nest the accesses:

```
Cos[phi0 + 2 f0 π t + k π t^2][[1, 2]]
```

There are of course several other ways to do this, but for starters this is probably the easiest way.